# Severely dehydrated. Any "quick" way to fix that?

Tags: water, dehydration

I've been dehydrated (among other things) for the last 3 or so years due to stress and other factors, but I'm really beginning to feel it now. I am trying to drink water more, but that's hard when all you're surrounded by seems to be junk..Still, I will try my best. I am just wondering if there is anything else I can do to fix this problem faster than drinking gallons of water.

My scalp is also very brittle in addition to me having dry lips because of the dehydration :/ I just turned 19 if that information is needed at all.

Any help/advice is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Drink enough and you won't be dehydrated unless you are ill. It's as simple as that. So if you think you're dehydrated despite consuming a normal amount of water for your climate and exercise level, then you need to see a doctor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're finding it difficult to get in the habit of drinking enough water, there are lots of other ways to increase your fluid intake. In addition to getting enough fluids when you are dehydrated, it is also important to replenish electrolytes and minerals in your body, and this will help you to hydrate yourself more quickly than simply drinking lots of water. Here are my suggestions:

1. Sports drinks like Gatorade contain electrolytes and may be more appealing to you than water. If you prefer a less sugary option, coconut water also contains high levels of electrolytes.
2. You can also make an oral re-hydration solution (ORS) at home, simply mix 4 cups water with 6 small spoonfuls of sugar, and a half a small spoonful of salt and mix to dissolve. This will restore lost fluids and minerals more quickly than plain water.
3. You can also eat watery fruits and vegetables to re-hydrate yourself more quickly, as these not only have high water content but will replenish lost minerals -watermelon, cantaloupe, grapefruit, oranges, strawberries, cucumber, grapes, papaya, celery, lettuce, spinach, zucchini and tomatoes are some good examples. If you don't like to eat these foods plain, consider blending into a smoothie.
4. Dehydration causes loss of minerals like potassium - eat 1-2 bananas a day to replenish your potassium.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Welcome to Health.SE. Since health is an important topic, the site has a strict policy that **all answers** should be [backed up with reliable references](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers) in order to provide the community with the means to assess the merit of the answer, regardless of the reader's background. *See [this list of reliable sources](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112/what-are-reliable-sources)*. If you still have trouble with this, feel free to visit the [help].